# Can NUNIT, a unit-testing framework, be used for integration testing?

Tags: vb.net, nunit, integration-testing

Can NUNIT, a unit-testing framework, be used for integration testing? It seems to be working that way for me now. Are there other automated testing frameworks out for integration testing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **you can use NUnit for integration testing**. For that, you may take an advantage of attributes like `[Setup]` and `[TearDown]`.

Other .NET unit test frameworks which can be used for integration testing as well are:

- MSTest
- xUnit.NET

For more testing framework types (UI testing, database testing, web testing, acceptance testing, etc.), you may check [List of Automated Testing (TDD/BDD/ATDD/SBE) Tools and Frameworks for .NET](https://github.com/dariusz-wozniak/List-of-Testing-Tools-and-Frameworks-for-.NET).